# How to install wordpress with MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, nginx, mariadb

I am trying to install wordpress on my nginx + mariadb

First step of: pointing my url to

```
http://localhost/wordpress/
```

is throwing following error:

```
Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.
```

I hope many other people are using wordpress with mariadb.

[EDIT]

Using WNMP for bundle installation of ( Nginx + MariaDB + PHP )

Comment: I use this light [WNMP stack](https://wnmplight.rami-lab.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this helps you, its for Windows 7. Here are the steps

## Get the files

Download only the compressed files which do not require installation to use the programs

1. get the Xeoncross’ WNMP `https://github.com/Xeoncross/wnmp`
2. get memcached `http://code.jellycan.com/memcached/`
3. get MySQL `http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/`
4. get nginx `http://nginx.org/en/download.html`
5. get PHP `http://windows.php.net/download/`
6. get phpMyAdmin `http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php`
7. get wordpress `http://www.wordpress.org/`

## Place the files

1. extract the content of WNMP to `d:wemp`
2. extract the memcached.exe to `d:wempmemcached`
3. extract the contents of MySQL to `d:wempMySQL`
4. extract the contents of nginx to `d:wempnginx`
5. extract the content of PHP to `d:wempPHP`
6. extract the content of phpMyAmdin to `d:wempwwwphpMyAdmin`
7. extract the content of wordpress to `d:wempwwwwordpress`

## Configure

1. for MySQL, rename `d:wempMySQLmy-small.ini` to `my.ini`
2. for NginX, copy `d:wempexample.nginx.conf` to `d:wempnginxconf`, rename `nginx.conf` to `nginx.conf.bak` and rename `example.nginx.conf` to `nginx.conf`
3. for PHP, rename `d:wempPHPphp.ini` - development to `php.ini`
4. open the `php.ini` file in a text editor, remove the `;` preceeding `extension_dir = "ext"`
5. remove the `;` preceeding `cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1`
6. remove the `;` preceeding `extension=php_mbstring.dll`
7. remove the `;` preceeding `extension=php_mysql.dll`, save the file

## Run

1. run `d:wempstart_server.bat` to start running, a few command prompt windows will pop up and disappear

## Confirm they are running

1. open task manager by pressing `Ctrl + Shift + Esc`
2. check `php-cgi.exe`, `memcached.exe`, `mysqld.exe`, `nginx.exe` are running
3. run the following command in command prompt to change the root password of MySQL `d:wempmysqlbinmysqladmin -u root password hereIsYourPassword`
4. If face problem starting `mysqld.exe` than look the error in `d:wempmysqldataerr.log`

## Test the server and install WordPress

1. start a browser (make sure there is no proxy)
2. visit `http://localhost/`
3. see the WNMP success page
4. visit `http://localhost/phpMyAdmin/`
5. log in with username root, password hereIsYourPassword!
6. create a database with the name wordpress
7. visit `http://localhost/wordpress/`
8. start the famous 5 mins installation of wordpress

Comment: Are you saying wnpm install is not a good choice ? as I have installed and everything is working fine, phpmyadmin, aliasing, etc.

Comment: No that was just if you are doing it manual, otherwise you should start from 3rd Configure section!!!

Comment: I didn't understand all this when there is auto installer available. Finally I found the problem which is in wnmp install it disable the mysql extention i.e. point 7 under configure section of your answer, Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

mariadb is 100% compatible with the mysql interface in php
i think you're missing the module for php

depending on the distribution you're using i'd say do a

> sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd

you can make sure the mysql mod is enabled by doing a **phpinfo();**

when running php5-fpm with nginx make sure the module is enabled at the right place

> /etc/php5/fpm/

Comment: phpinfo() says: php ver is 5.5.13 and mysqlnd is enabled 5.0.11 in "loaded plugins" i can see mysqlnd, debug_trace, etc.